# I installed Ubuntu 14 and accidently removed Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I wanted to install Ubuntu 14 alongside Windows 7 today (Windows was already installed).

In the install menu i choose the "something else option" and gave Ubuntu 200 gb + 8gb for swap like 56mb for /boot thingy and made a 10 gb partition to move files between windows and Ubuntu.

Those are the Partitions which Ubuntu detects

[image: Partition Table]

Since i installed Ubuntu, Windows does not show up when i boot my PC , it just goes to ubuntu instantly and does not give me an option to choose.

Is there a way to recover the windows installation or the  files? There are so many files i lost now :(

Comment: Was Windows installed in the 4th partition? or did you have to make room for Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks like you wrote over Windows 7 when installing. Best case would be to stop using the machine and try recovering the files with some kind of file recovery software.

Comment: Windows should be on the 4th partition. Think it would be possible to see the windows folder structure if i connect the hard drive to a windows or if i just install windows again?

Answer (score 1):

Well from the picture you provided there is no NTFS partition. So you may have accidentally deleted the Windows partition. If so, your best bet is it to try some kind of recovery software.

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a great utility for recovering lost and damaged partitions.

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`